# Pooled NpgsqlConnection's relationship with PostgreSQL sessions

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I'm looking for some concrete information about how connections and connection pooling in Npgsql translates to PostgreSQL's idea of a 'session'. Specifically:

- Is an `NpgsqlConnection.Open` synonymous with creating a new session?
- Assuming the above is true, is that also ALWAYS true when connection pooling is enabled and a connection is reused?
- Is there any risk of session-based configurations (`set_config` / `current_setting`) 'leaking' between pooled connections?

For context, I want to use session-based settings to enforce multi-tenancy RLS policies, but I want to rule out the possibility of connection pooling causing leaks in corner cases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272654/640325 for some background.

When Npgsql pooling is enabled (default) NpgsqlConnection.Open is definitely not synonymous with creating a new session (or physical connection to PG) - a connection may be taken out of Npgsql's pool and returned instead, which is much faster. When pooling is off, Open is indeed synonymous with creating a new PG session.

However, even pooling is on, Npgsql takes care to reset the connection state when it is returned to the pool (via [DISCARD ALL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-discard.html)). The effect is that after NpgsqlConnection.Open, your connection state should be the same as it would have been if a totally new PG session were opened (i.e. if pooling were off). This means that no state leaking should occur, even when pooling is enabled.