# What is the maximum number of connection allowed to Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql

Connecting from .net application to PostgresDB. There are 20+ applications connecting.
How many connection does postgre support in total.

Connection string sample:

"ConnectionString": "......... Pooling=true; Minimum Pool Size=**50**; Maximum Pool Size=**200**;"

*In docs noticed its mentioned 100+15, But on some applications it have 50 Minimum pool already*

Comment: Pooling is a clientside strategy, it doesn't affect the connection limit of the database itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272459/postgres-npgsql-connection-pooling

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-MAX-CONNECTIONS

Comment: We have 250 JVM's and each one has a connection pool of 10 connections. 10 connections to the connection pool we have put in front of the database to avoid direct connections from the applications. The database has a maximum of just 50 connections and that is more than enough for the 5 million daily users we serve. So instead of a maximum of 2500 connections, we have just 50. And when really busy, there are just 12 to 15 active connections, the rest is idle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit on the server size is determined by `max_connections` - `superuser_reserved_connections` (both of which are PostgreSQL parameters). The default value is 97.  In addition, you can set a connection limit on the database and the database user.

However, if you are even getting close to the limit of 97 connections, you are probably doing something wrong: either you have no connection pool, or the connection pool is defined too large. Only *very* powerful hardware could handle hundred active processes.